# ¿Cómo generar números enteros aleatorios en C en un rango concreto?

Tags: c, random

Estoy haciendo un algoritmo que genere e ingrese en una matriz valores de forma aleatoria, pero que los números estén dentro de un rango de 18 a 60, porque mi matriz va a almacenar la edad de los empleados de una empresa y quiero que el programa genere los números de forma aleatoria porque ya estoy cansado de estar ingresando valores de uno en uno. Además, debe ser en una matriz 6x6.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int num, arr[6][6];
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <6; j++){  
            num=rand() % 11;
            arr[i][j] = num;    
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <6; j++){
            printf ("[%i] ", arr[i][j]);    
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como explicó Ryan Reich en una [pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6852396/13146539), las soluciones más intuitivas (que acaban usando el operador `%` o estrategias similares) suelen ser matemáticamente erróneas y provocan que algunos valores sean generados con mayor frecuencia que otros, dando lugar a una generación de valores sesgada.

- **Nota:** Las soluciones que propongo a continuación servirán generar valores entre un mínimo y un máximo, *ambos inclusive*.

#### Solución corta, pero sesgada

Si no te importa sufrir este inconveniente, podemos usar la [solución de John y SleuthEye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29382078/13146539):

```c
int random_int(int min, int max)
{
   return min + rand() % (max + 1 - min);
}
```

Esta función es vulnerable frente a ciertas situaciones y podría generar salidas no deseadas, pero es rápida de implementar. En tu caso, puede resultarte útil. Tu programa quedaría de la siguiente forma.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// Cabecera de la función
int random_int(int min, int max);

int main() {
    int num, arr[6][6];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <6; j++){  
            num = random_int(18, 60); //
            arr[i][j] = num;    
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <6; j++){
            printf ("[%i] ", arr[i][j]);    
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int random_int(int min, int max)
{
   return min + rand() % (max + 1 - min);
}
```

#### Solución larga y precisa

Utilizando la función de Ryan Reich como base, podemos reescribir el programa para que genere los valores que necesitas. Esta vez, siendo rigurosos con que sean equiprobables y manejando posibles errores.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// Cabecera de la función
long randomInRange(long min, long max);

int main() {
    int num, arr[6][6], min, max;
    srand(time(NULL));

    min = 18;
    max = 60;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            num = (int)randomInRange((long)min, (long)max);
            arr[i][j] = num;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            printf("[%i] ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

// FUNCIÓN DE RYAN REICH, PERO CON VALOR MÍNIMO
// Assumes 0 <= max <= RAND_MAX
// Returns in the closed interval [0, max]
long randomInRange(long min, long max) {
    if (min < max) {
        unsigned long
            // max <= RAND_MAX < ULONG_MAX, so this is okay.
            num_bins = (unsigned long)max - (unsigned long)min + 1,
            num_rand = (unsigned long)RAND_MAX + 1,
            bin_size = num_rand / num_bins,
            defect = num_rand % num_bins;

        long x;
        do {
            x = random();
        }
        // This is carefully written not to overflow
        while (num_rand - defect <= (unsigned long)x);

        // Truncated division is intentional
        return x / bin_size + min;
    }
    else {
        printf("Error, el rango no es válido.\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva mi respuesta, y bienvenido a la comunidad de Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

¡Qué tal, @Anzarpe97!

El secreto está en esta sintaxis:

```c
int numeroAletorio = minimo + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (maximo - (minimo) + 1) + 1);
```

En mínimo y máximo colocas el rango que necesites.

---

Por ejemplo

Código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(){
  srand( time( NULL ) );

  int numeroAletorio = 18 + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (60 - 18 + 1) + 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    numeroAletorio = 18 + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (60 - 18 + 1) + 1);;
    printf("%d\n", numeroAletorio);
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Terminal:

```sh
38
59
18
31
49
54
29
23
48
56
```

Saludos, ten bonita noche.

Comment: Lee atentamente. La pregunta dice que quiere generar edades aleatorias. Normalmente la expresamos en números enteros. El código que le muestras es para generar números con decimales y le falta la conversión a float.

Comment: El código que proporcioné solo genera números enteros en un rango de 18 a 60.

En el ejemplo de la terminal se puede apreciar mejor.

Saludos.

Comment: Nome hice entender bien. Me refiero a que estás usando la forma para calcular float aleatorios solo que ignoras los decimales. Lo puedes simplificar así: `mínimo + rand() % (máximo - mínimo)`

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, @Mateo.

No sabía que mi código era propenso a dar número flotantes, apenas me estoy adentrando en el mundo de la programación y tengo algunos fallos.